# YQL global response object converts binary data to raw binary string incorrectly

Tags: javascript, binary, response, yql

***I have asked the same question on YDN forum, too. --> [post on YQL forum](https://developer.yahoo.com/forums/#/discussion/6365/yql-global-response-object-coverts-binary-data-to-raw-binary-string-incorrectly)***

It is said in **https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-javascript-objects.html#yql-execute-responseglobalobject**:

> Get the response from the remote service.** If the response content
>   type is not application/json or text/xml then YQL provides a string.**
>   If JSON or XML is specified, the E4X representation of the data is
>   returned.

---

But if response content is binary data (for example image/jpeg), YQL cannot convert it to raw binary string literal(in JSON format) correctly. I have figured out that YQL failed for 2 characters: \u000D (\n) not \u000A (\n), \u00A0 (non-breaking-space) not \u0020 (space). It is impossible to recover the original binary data from YQL output. **Definitely it's a BUG, and a bugfix is welcomed.**

Is there a way to change some settings to avoid the problem, or YQL team will correct its engine in near future? It will be grateful if YQL can support binary content as response.

P.S.
you can try query as below on YQL console with Community Tables ON (check JSON output):
**[Execute on YQL console](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20*%20from%20data.uri%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fl.yimg.com%2Fa%2Fi%2Fus%2Fpps%2Fyql32.png%22&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys#h=select%20*%20from%20execute%20where%20code%3D%22var%20url%3D%27http%3A%2F%2Ftechblogcorner.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2014%2F09%2Fjpeg.jpg%27%2C%20req%20%3D%20y.rest%28url%29.accept%28%27image%27%29.header%28%27Accept-Encoding%27%2C%20%27gzip%2Cdeflate%27%29.decompress%28true%29%2C%20resp%20%3D%20req.get%28%29%3B%20response.object%3D%20resp.response%3B%22)**

```
select * from execute where code="var url='http://techblogcorner.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/jpeg.jpg', req = y.rest(url).accept('image').header('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip,deflate').decompress(true), resp = req.get(); response.object= resp.response;"
```

Here is source code of a live sample client querying yql.

(also on JSBin: **http://jsbin.com/gasikocecu/2/edit?js,output**)

```js
var url = 'http://techblogcorner.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/jpeg.jpg';
$('#origin').css('background-image', 'url(' + url + ')');
$.ajax(exec(url)).done(function(data, _, jqxhr) {
                 console.log('data', data);
  if (data.query.results) {
    data = data.query.results.result;
    data = data.resp.response;
    console.log(data.length);
    data = toab(data);
                 
    console.log(data);
                 
    var blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'image'}),
        blobUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);


    $('#fault').empty().css('background-image', 'url(' + blobUrl + ')');
  } else {
    $('#fault').empty().text('YQL failed, please re-run JS.');
  }
 });

function exec(url) {
    return  {
        url: 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql',
        data: {
            format: 'json',
            q: 'select * from execute where code="' + "var url='" + url +
                "', req = y.rest(url).accept('image').header('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip,deflate').decompress(true);" +
                'var resp = req.get(); response.object= {req: req.headers, resp: resp};"',
            env: 'store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys'
        }
    };
}

function toab(str) {
    var len = str.length, bytes = new Uint8Array(len);
    for (var i = 0; i<len; i++)
        bytes[i] = str.charCodeAt(i) & 0xFF;
    return bytes;
}
```

```css
.fancy {
  margin: 16px;
  width: 240px;
  height: 240px;
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
  box-shadow: 
    2px 2px 2px 2px rgba(100,100,100, 0.2),
    4px 4px 4px 4px rgba(100,100,100, 0.1);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  padding: 1em;
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>YQL: response as binary data</title>
</head>
<body>
  original image:
  <div id="origin" class="fancy"></div>
  retrived via YQL:
  <div id="fault" class="fancy"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Running result of the original jpeg image file(top), and yql corrupted one(bottom) are attached below. Binary comparison shows yql global response object mistaking \u000A(\n) for \u000D(\r), \u0020(space) for \u00A0(non-breaking-space) when output raw binary string literal.
[image]
[image]

Comment: yql is meant for data, not binary files. you can DIY with 1 line of php...

Comment: I just don't want any server stuff besides yql.

Comment: well then i'm afraid your'e stuck with what they offer...

Comment: In fact I'm creating a prototype but need to access cross domain content, which yql is useful for me but not critical.